# How can I convert timezone like America/Los_Angeles to TZ variable?

Tags: timezone, converters

How can I convert all timezone like America/Los_Angeles, or Europe/Moscow to next format for TZ var:

```
stdoffset[dst[offset],date[/time],date[/time]]
```

Like this:

```
America/Los_Angeles --> PST8PDT,M4.1.0/02:00,M10.5.0/02:00
Amsterdam/Netherlands  -->  CET-1CEST-2,M3.5.0/02:00:00,M10.5.0/03:00:00
Europe/Moscow --> ???
Europe/Istanbul --> ???
...
and so on for all timezones.
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with the results?  You can usually use the tzdb name directly.  See the "third" format here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will use the third format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the IANA database: http://www.iana.org/time-zones

It contains a regularly maintained set of time zone names with history.

Comment: I know about this base and try to use it. @Matt Johnson ' comment helped my. P.S. Sorry for my English